# native c++ code logging support on azure

Tags: logging, azure, native-code

Is there any support for "logging functionality" for native c++ code running in azure cloud?
I have a native code spawned from the azure worker role. Once the native code starts, can I log the status of native executable to azure blob or azure WADLogs? So that without remote logging , logs can be checked through the blob viewers.

Comment: Do the native c++ trace methods send output to stdout?  If you are using Process.Spawn (to spawn the process in your worker role) then you have the option of listening to stdout. The listener could then route messages to the standard azure trace listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin functionality to for native code however if your module can write logs to specific folder or in the event log, Azure Diagnostics can pull it from there and write to Azure Blob/WAD blob storage. There could be other ways as well but I can suggest a few  ways you can achieve your objective.

Once you have enabled Azure Diagnostics in your Worker role first you can use any of TWO options as below:

1. Configure Azure Diagnostics to read logs from a specific folder in your Azure Local Storage. Now modify your native module to write all the logs in the specific Local Storage folder and rest of the job to collect logs from local storage folder and then sending to Azure WAD container will be taken care by Azure Diagnostics. I think this is the easiest option. Here is an [article](http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/custom-diagnostics-in-windows-azure/) explaining how to configure Azure Role to read/transfer logs from a specific folder.
2. If you can configure Azure Diagnostics to collect Event logs, you can write directly to Event log from your native module and Azure Diagnostics will move event logs to Azure WAD storage.

If you don't want to use Azure Diagnostics at all, you can write directly to Azure Blob Storage from your native module and REST API. Little harder but you sure can do it.